# different results in different smart phones

Tags: android

I'm creating a compass application in which image of the compass should be straight at 267 degrees. The results are so accurate in my 'Q mobile noir A51' which has 4.5" screen and have android version 4.3 jelly bean. But when I'm testing it in 'Samsung Galaxy Grand' which has 5" screen and same version of android it will give different results. Then I test it in 'sony xperia L' which have 4" screen and same version of android again the result is different than Galaxy grand and Qmobile. Please tell me what will be the reason behind it? Is there a problem  with the screen size or the sensors of every smart phones are different? I'm putting the images of the result below.

[image: Here is the Qmobile result]
[image: Galaxy Grand result is this. The result should be 267 degrees at this point and image should be straight. But it is giving 244 degrees]

Galaxy Grand result is this. The result should be 267 degrees at this point and image should be straight.
Sony xperia is not available right now so i could post it's result but it's also giving the different result.

P.S: result in galaxy grand is keep on changing as the screen lock button press. When the scree open the result changes itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is what you say in principle this depends on the hardware of each manufacturer, the accuracy of hw.

So many sides talk about the compass calibration software, hardware and even some mutts.

This is an example:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP3d00Hr14o